# Can odds ratios be negative?

Tags: logistic

Since the odds ratio is defined as

$OR = \frac{P(A)}{1-P(A)} / \frac{P(B)}{1-P(B)}$, where 
$P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are between 0 and 1

How can an odds ratio be negative?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It cannot be negative. However, the (often natural) logarithm of it can be. Usually, an odds ratio is actually derived on the log-transformed scale (where confidence intervals derived based on log-odds ratio $\pm 1.96 \times $ SE work better) and estimate & confidence intervals are the transformed onto the odds ratio scale for reporting.

Answer (score 4):

It simply can not be negative.
Perhaps you read somewhere about negative values of logarithm of odds rato or the logit function defined as $\ln(p)$ where $p$ is $\frac{OR}{1+OR}$